# Correct way to redirect url to specific language with parameter at the end of the url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I would need is to redirect with htaccess an url that has already some google analytics parameters in it, and redirect it adding the language parameter at the end of the url. I tried this with no luck so far but I know its wrong at some point:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^random?$1 http://www.domain.com/random?$1&language=french [R=301,QSA]
```

I'm trying with $1, I don't know if this is correct, the intention of which is to include all the parameters like utm_source=1&utm_medium=2, after this I would need to include the language parameter, so redirected url should look like http://www.domain.com/random?utm_source=1&utm_medium=2&language=french.

What is the right way to achieve what I need?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Back-References**

In your rule, `$1` is a back-reference to a capture group that doesn't yet exist.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*language=french
RewriteRule ^(random.*) $1?language=french [R=301,QSA,L]
```

- At the beginning `^` of the url path, `(random.*)` matches `random` and the rest of the url. (So we are only rewriting urls that start with `random`... is that what you want?)
- We rewrite with the back-reference `$1`, followed by the query string `?language=french`
- The `QSA` flag ensures that existing query-string parameters are added.

Comment: FYI: added explanation. Are you sure you only want to rewrite urls that start with `random`?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and explanation, I tried but redirection is giving the full path to the template and therefore is a 404 error: http://domain.com/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/... what should be edited in that rule to make it work correctly? random?language=french shows correctly.

Comment: Full path? What url did you put it, and what url did you get out?

Comment: I copied the same rule you edited, output is: http://www.domain.com/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/random?language=french&utm_source=.....

Comment: Yeah, I got that from your earlier comment. You haven't answered my question.

Comment: domain.com/random?utm_source=bla is the url I put

Comment: Thanks for that. Before your RewriteCond, try adding `RewriteBase /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/` . Other than that, no idea, sorry.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. We need a condition to prevent multiple rewrites. Added a condition. This is working on my server, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hey thank you for your help, I tried but it keeps showing the full path, don't know what can be wrong, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I solved it, I added http://www.domain.com/random?language=french instead of the $1?language=french.. Thanks a lot for your help! :)